# How to insert a varchar that contains a floating comma in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I'm trying to execute some data in a table. The issue is that I have to insert the name `O'Donnel` into a field named `name` and I'm getting a format error.

```
insert into Person (name) values ('O'Donnel');
```

I also don't want to use double floating commas ("") because I'm inserting this data using a JDBC system and `Strings` in Java already use those.

So... is there any other solution?

Comment: `insert into Person (name) values ('O''Donnel');`, i.e. double the quote inside a string literal.

Comment: .. or standard escaping with backslash - `insert into Person (name) values ('O\'Donnel')`. See [String Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html).

Comment: Doubled single quote is according to the ANSI/ISO SQL standard.

Answer (score -2):

**Try This**

```
INSERT INTO Person(name) VALUES ("O'Donnel");
```

Comment: I guess that would work, but as I said in the answer, I was looking an alternative to this.
This worked for me: `INSERT INTO PERSON (name) VALUES ('O''Donnel');` as @jarlh said.